# Automatically run python function in odoo with using cron job?

Tags: python, odoo-14

How to run python function automatically and send email in odoo14 without using cron jobs?

Comment: What do you mean automatically? Continuously? Or at certain times?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Automation which can be found here : in App Settings, switch to debug mode by adding "?debug=1" in your url, reload the page, then go to the new Technical Menu-tab > Automation - automated action / Server actions

[image]

[image]

Or using Python Code :

```
   #select an existing template:
   template_id = env.ref('event.event_subscription').id
   env['mail.template'].browse(template_id).sudo().send_mail(cur_registrations[0].id, force_send=True)
```

Other resources on this topic :

- https://odootricks.tips/about/building-blocks/server-actions/
- https://rubeshan.com/odoo-automated-actions-send-email-via-python-code/
- https://en.ngasturi.id/2020/12/06/how-to-send-an-email-in-odoo/